# How to make /login route accessible only for anonymous users in Symfony4?

Tags: php, authentication, symfony4

My `access_controll` looks like:

```
- { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
- { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER}
```

I need to give an access to route `/login` only to anonymously authenticated users.

Comment: Also have a look here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/security.html - current practice is to deny. So allow anonymous to all routes, then deny to routes requiring login, e.g. "ROLE_ADMIN" required for `- { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }`, et cetera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, there's a better variant to do this even with redirect. Firstable, you need to edit `security.yaml` with this:

```
access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER}
```

And then just add this to your `SecurityController::login()` method:

```
if ($this->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
        return new RedirectResponse(
            $this->generateUrl('index')
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the solution:

```
- { path: ^/login, allow_if: 'is_anonymous()'}
```